# AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'set_configuration'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, codec

I would want to collect DATA from a USB audio codec connected to a raspberry pi.
So first I'm trying a simple program to write some data

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xfffe, idProduct=0x0001)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
raise ValueError('Device not found')

# set the active configuration. With no arguments, the first
# configuration will be the active one
dev.set_configuration()

# get an endpoint instance
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]

ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)

assert ep is not None

# write the data
ep.write('test')
```

Here is my error :
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'set_configuration'

Here is what the tutorial says about this function :
After, we set the configuration to use. Note that no argument indicating what configuration we want was supplied. As you will see, many PyUSB functions have defaults for most common devices. In this case, the configuration set is the first one found.

So I didn't understand why I'm getting this error.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: Fix the indentation on `raise ValueError('Device not found')`

Comment: Yeah thanks I did that in my code but I badly copy paste x)

Comment: Try adding an explicit `find_all=False` in your `usb.core.find` call

Comment: What is printed if you add a line `print dev` after the usb.core.find call?

Comment: print dev gives me a long list of all the features of my USB device (bLength, bDescriptorType, bcdUSB...)

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggests that `usb.core.find` is a generator function. That is, it returns an iterable generator object, not a single device object, like you seem to expect. You need to iterate over the generator in some way (e.g. with a `for` loop, or by passing it to `list`) to get the device objects. You may need to add logic to your code to deal with not only getting zero devices (e.g. the `"Device not found"` case), but also to deal with getting more than one!

Comment: The error does certainly suggests that ... although the actual docs suggest that `usb.core.find` returns an actual item (or None), not an iterator  (unless you pass `find_all=True` in which case it returns you an iterator over all devices satisfying your criteria).

Comment: I have tried to add a while loop like this: while dev is None: dev=usb.core.find(find_all=True, bDeviceClass=1) but I get NameError: name 'dev' is not defined. So how can I defined my object dev ?

Comment: I think a package is missing because I also have AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get_active_configuration'...